# Storing Data In Memory: Session vs Cache vs Static

Tags: memory, session, caching, static

A bit of backstory:  I am working on an web application that requires quite a bit of time to prep / crunch data before giving it to the user to edit / manipulate.  The data request task ~ 15 / 20 secs to complete and a couple secs to process.  Once there, the user can manipulate vaules on the fly.  Any manipulation of values will require the data to be reprocessed completely.

Update:  To avoid confusion, I am only making the data call 1 time (the 15 sec hit) and then wanting to keep the results in memory so that I will not have to call it again until the user is 100% done working with it.  So, the first pull will take a while, but, using Ajax, I am going to hit the in-memory data to constantly update and keep the response time to around 2 secs or so (I hope).

In order to make this efficient, I am moving the intial data into memory and using Ajax calls back to the server so that I can reduce processing time to handle the recalculation that occurs w/ this user's updates.

Here is my question, with performance in mind, what would be the best way to storing this data, assuming that only 1 user will be working w/ this data at any given moment.

Also, the user could potentially be working in this process for a few hours.  When the user is working w/ the data, I will need some kind of failsafe to save the user's current data (either in a db or in a serialized binary file) should their session be interrupted in some way. In other words, I will need a solution that has an appropriate hook to allow me to dump out the memory object's data in the case that the user gets disconnected / distracted for too long.

So far, here are my musings:

Session State - Pros:  Locked to one user.  Has the Session End event which will meet my failsafe requirements.  Cons: Slowest perf of the my current options.  The Session End event is sometimes tricky to ensure it fires properly.

Caching - Pros: Good Perf.  Has access to dependencies which could be a bonus later down the line but not really useful in current scope.  Cons:  No easy failsafe step other than a write based on time intervals.  Global in scope - will have to ensure that users do not collide w/ each other's work.

Static - Pros:  Best Perf.  Easies to maintain as I can directly leverage my current class structures.  Cons:  No easy failsafe step other than a write based on time intervals.  Global in scope - will have to ensure that users do not collide w/ each other's work.

Does anyone have any suggestions / comments on what I option I should choose?

Thanks!

Update:  Forgot to mention, I am using VB.Net, Asp.Net, and Sql Server 2005 to perform this task.

Comment: It's usually cheaper to upgrade your sever than to spend time optimizing your code. I believe Jeff Atwood said something about it on his blog lately.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific w/ performance.  I don't worry so much about the server handling the memory usage, but, rather, how long it will take to get my response back to the user.

Comment: What language/tech are you using?

Comment: Lol, could have specified that.  In this case, I am using VB.Net, Asp.Net, and Sql Server 2005

Comment: The best article with examples I have read. You should read, it clarifies what you ask. https://dzone.com/articles/cache-vs-session-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the caching method of for storing the data across any page loads.  You can name the cache you want to store the data in to avoid conflicts.

For tracking user-made changes, I'd go with a more old-school approach: append to a text file each time the user makes a change and then sweep that file at intervals to save changes back to DB.  If you name the files based on the user/account or some other session-unique indicator then there's no issue with conflict and the app (or some other support app, which might be a better idea in general) can sweep through all such files and update the DB even if the session is over.

The first part of this can be adjusted to stagger the write out more: save changes to Session, then write that to file at intervals, then sweep the file at larger intervals.  you can tune it to performance and choose what level of possible user-change loss will be possible.

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly the kind of approach I was looking for.  I apprecaite it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll vote for secret option #4: use the database for this. If you're talking about a 20+ second turnaround time on the data, you are not going to gain anything by trying to do this in-memory, given the limitations of the options you presented. You might as well set this up in the database (give it a table of its own, or even a separate database if the requirements are that large).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session, but don't rely on it.

Simply, let the user "name" the dataset, and make a point of actively persisting it for the user, either automatically, or through something as simple as a "save" button.

You can not rely on the session simply because it is (typically) tied to the users browser instance. If they accidentally close the browser (click the X button, their PC crashes, etc.), then they lose all of their work. Which would be nasty.

Once the user has that kind of control over the "persistent" state of the data, you can rely on the Session to keep it in memory and leverage that as a cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've pretty much just answered your question with the pros/cons.  But if you are looking for some peer validation, my vote is for the Session.  Although the performance is slower (do you know by how much slower?), your processing is going to take a long time regardless.  Do you think the user will know the difference between 15 seconds and 17 seconds?  Both are "forever" in web terms, so go with the one that seems easiest to implement.

perhaps a bit off topic.  I'd recommend putting those long processing calls in asynchronous (not to be confused with AJAX's asynchronous) pages.

Take a look at this article and ping me back if it doesn't make sense.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Comment: I guess I was not 100% clear.  My goal is to do the 15 / 20 sec hit of pulling the data into the session / cache / static vars and then save those while the user makes their updates / changes.  That way, I only have to do the hit 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a copy of the data in a new database table (let's call it EDIT) as you send the initial results to the user. If performance is an issue, do this in a background thread.

As the user edits the data, update the table (also in a background thread if performance becomes an issue). If you have to use threads, you must make sure that the first thread is finished before you start updating the rows.

This allows a user to walk away, come back, even restart the browser and commit whenever she feels satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative to what the others mentioned, is to store the data on the client.
Assuming the dataset is not too large, and the code that manipulates it can be handled client side. You could store the data as an XML data island or JSON object. This data could then be manipulated/processed and handled all client side with no round trips to the server. If you need to persist this data back to the server the end resulting data could be posted via an AJAX or standard postback.

If this does not work with your requirements I'd go with just storing it on the SQL server as the other comment suggested.